# Vertical alignment of lines change based on letters having a descender or tail

Tags: vertical-alignment, characters

I am currently having issues with vertial alignment based on the type of character being inputted. If I use a character that has some sort of descender or tail, it adjusts the height of the `\hrule` that appears under the text. This can be seen in the image below, in which the `p` of `pppaaa` is shifting the `\hrule`.

[image: Sample Text]

To create this, I am using a small custom command which is the following

```
\newcommand{\customHeading}[1] {
    \begin{flushleft}
        \LARGE{#1}
    \end{flushleft}
    \hrule height 1.5pt
}
```

Now, I could just use a `\vspace{...}`, in which I pass a custom spacing parameter for each new `\customHeading` but that seems a tad hacky. I was hoping there would be a better way of adjusting the alignment, in which I am open to suggestions!

**Note** - I looked at the following [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/635814/vertical-spacing-around-the-text-in-the-title-of-a-tcolorbox), but using those ideas, I couldn't really fix my issue.

Comment: Hi and welcome. Maybe a `\strut` can help?

Comment: I tried that and it didn't seem to have much affect. The descender still shifted the `\hrule`

Comment: A strut would be bigger than the descender of p so both lines would be the same,or you could use latex `\rule` instead of the tex prmitive `\hrule` then the spacing would be the same.

Comment: unrelated but `\LARGE{#1}` should be `\LARGE#1` size commands do not take an argument.

Comment: Since there's plenty of room below the text, you probably want to ignore the descender,  Try `\smash[b]{...}`.  If the text extends to more than one line, apply the `\smash` to only the last line.

Comment: Epic! Thanks for all the responses. I used a combination of all the above and it looks a lot better!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to produce something that looks a lot better, based on all the comments from above!
It now looks like the following, in which everything is aligned as expected.

[image: underlined text]

This was produced with the following snippet

```
\newcommand{\customHeading}[1]{
    \noindent\smash{\LARGE #1}
    \strut
    \hrule height 1pt
}
```

This could probably be improved further, if you replace `\hrule` with `\rule`, but the above worked for me so I kept it as is.